# accumulator of Spark is confusing me.

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am practicing Apache Spark but encountering the following problem.

```
val accum = sc.accumulator( 0, "My Accumulator.")
println (accum)  // print out: 0

sc.parallelize( Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ).foreach( x => accum += x ) 
// sc.parallelize( Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ).foreach( x => accum = accum + x )
println( accum.value ) // print out: 15
```

This line of code `sc.parallelize( Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ).foreach( x => accum += x )` is working quite well, but the code commented out below it is not working. The difference is:

```
x => accum += x
```

and

```
x => accum = accum + x
```

Why the second one is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three reasons why it doesn't work:

1. `accum` is a value so it cannot be reassigned
2. `Accumulable` class, which is a base class for `Accumulator` provides only `+=` method, not `+`
3. accumulators are write-only from the worker perspective so you cannot read the value inside an action. Theoretically `+` method could modify `accum` in place, but it would be rather confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Because believing it or not, an `Accumulator` in `Apache Spark` works like a write-only global variable, in our imperative thinking we don't see any difference between `x += 1` and `x = x + 1`, but there is a slight difference, the second operation in `Apache Spark` would require to read the value, but the first one wouldn't, or in an easier (how zero said in his explanation) the method `+` isn't implemented for that class. [Apache Spark](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/BerkeleyX/CS100.1x/asset/Week2Lec4.pdf) on p. 41, you can read about how it works, the slides are extracted from the [Introduction to Big Data with Apache Spark](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x)

Comment: Thanks for the slides, they are great.